# Full outer join not giving the answer I need

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I am using PostgreSQL and am having difficulty with getting a series of queries that combine the data from two tables (t1, t2)

t1 is

| studyida | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | M | 1 |
| a | M | 2 |
| a | M | 3 |
| b | F | 4 |
| b | F | 5 |
| b | F | 6 |
| c | M | 13 |
| c | M | 14 |
| c | M | 15 |

and t2 is

| studyida | studyidb | gender | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | M | 3 |
| a | z | M | 4 |
| a | z | M | 5 |
| NULL | y | F | 7 |
| NULL | y | F | 8 |
| NULL | y | F | 9 |
| c | x | M | 10 |
| c | x | M | 11 |
| c | x | M | 12 |
| NULL | w | F | 7 |
| NULL | w | F | 8 |
| NULL | w | F | 9 |
| NULL | u | M | 7 |
| NULL | u | M | 8 |
| NULL | u | M | 9 |

t1 and t2 are related via StudyIDA and gender.  What I need is a comprehensive listing from both tables, including including the ages.  Sometimes the age in t1 equals the age in t2 (e.g. for StudyIDA=a, age=3) but most of the time it does not.

I am looking to create a table like this

| StudyIDA | StudyIDB | gender | ageA | ageB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | M | 1 |  |
| a | z | M | 2 |  |
| a | z | M | 3 | 3 |
| a | z | M |  | 4 |
| a | z | M |  | 5 |
| b | NULL | F | 4 |  |
| b | NULL | F | 5 |  |
| b | NULL | F | 6 |  |
| NULL | y | F |  | 7 |
| NULL | y | F |  | 8 |
| NULL | y | F |  | 9 |
| c | x | F | 13 |  |
| c | x | F | 14 |  |
| c | x | F | 15 |  |
| c | x | F |  | 10 |
| c | x | F |  | 11 |
| c | x | F |  | 12 |
| NULL | w | F |  | 7 |
| NULL | w | F |  | 8 |
| NULL | w | F |  | 9 |
| NULL | u | M |  | 7 |
| NULL | u | M |  | 8 |
| NULL | u | M |  | 9 |

I was thinking that first a full outer join of t1 and t2 would give me what I want but it does not.

Then I was thinking I need a listing of all the individuals (lets call it t3), and then do a series of inserts (e.g. t1+t3 and also t1+t3) into a new table to 'construct' what I need.  I am really stuck on the odd times when age in t1 equals the age in t2 (e.g. for StudyIDA=a, age=3).

I am still not getting what I need.  Here is my code so far

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1, t2, t3;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (StudyIDA VARCHAR, gender VARCHAR, age int);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES 
    ('a','M', 1),('a','M', 2),('a','M', 3),
    ('b','F', 4),('b','F', 5),('b','F', 6),
    ('c','M', 13),('c','M', 14),('c','M', 15);
SELECT * FROM t1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (StudyIDA VARCHAR, StudyIDB varchar, gender VARCHAR, age int);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES 
    ('a','z','M', 3), ('a','z','M', 4), ('a','z','M', 5),
    (NULL,'y','F', 7),(NULL,'y','F', 8),(NULL,'y','F', 9),
    ('c','x','M', 10),('c','x','M', 11),('c','x','M', 12),
    (NULL,'w','F', 7),(NULL,'w','F', 8),(NULL,'w','F', 9),
    (NULL,'u','M', 7),(NULL,'u','M', 8),(NULL,'u','M', 9);
SELECT * FROM t2;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t3 (StudyIDA_t1 VARCHAR, gender_t1 VARCHAR, StudyIDA_t2 VARCHAR,StudyIDB varchar,
    gender_t2 VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO t3
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT StudyIDA, gender FROM t1) a FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT StudyIDA, StudyIDB, gender FROM t2) b 
    ON a.StudyIDA=b.StudyIDA AND a.gender=b.gender
    ORDER BY a.StudyIDA;

SELECT * FROM t3 ORDER BY StudyIDA_t1;


SELECT 'IN t1', * 
    FROM t3 JOIN t1 on t1.StudyIDA=t3.StudyIDA_t1 AND t1.gender=t3.gender_t1
    ORDER BY StudyIDA_t1, StudyIDB;

SELECT 'In t2',* 
    FROM t3 JOIN t2 on t3.StudyIDA_t1=t2.StudyIDA AND t3.gender_t1=t2.gender
    ORDER BY StudyIDA_t1, t3.StudyIDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1, t2, t3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full join that includes the age maybe?
And some coalesce's for common fields.

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT 
>   COALESCE(t1.StudyIDA, t2.StudyIDA) AS StudyIDA
> , t2.StudyIDB 
> , COALESCE(t1.gender, t2.gender) AS gender
> , t1.age as ageA
> , t2.age as ageB
> FROM t1
> FULL JOIN t2 
>   ON t2.StudyIDA is not distinct from t1.StudyIDA
>  AND t2.gender = t1.gender 
>  AND t2.age = t1.age
> ORDER BY StudyIDA, gender, ageA, ageB;
> ```
>
> ```
> studyida | studyidb | gender | agea | ageb
> :------- | :------- | :----- | ---: | ---:
> a        | null     | M      |    1 | null
> a        | null     | M      |    2 | null
> a        | z        | M      |    3 |    3
> a        | z        | M      | null |    4
> a        | z        | M      | null |    5
> b        | null     | F      |    4 | null
> b        | null     | F      |    5 | null
> b        | null     | F      |    6 | null
> c        | null     | M      |   13 | null
> c        | null     | M      |   14 | null
> c        | null     | M      |   15 | null
> c        | x        | M      | null |   10
> c        | x        | M      | null |   11
> c        | x        | M      | null |   12
> null     | w        | F      | null |    7
> null     | y        | F      | null |    7
> null     | w        | F      | null |    8
> null     | y        | F      | null |    8
> null     | w        | F      | null |    9
> null     | y        | F      | null |    9
> null     | u        | M      | null |    7
> null     | u        | M      | null |    8
> null     | u        | M      | null |    9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e1757300b99daba15f4795b1834c0a78)*

Comment: I wish I could understand what you did!  One comment.  Notice that StudyIDB is NULL for some of StudyIDA=a and StudyIDA=c.  I'm not sure if that is going to matter later on.

Comment: But then why have StudyIDA='b'? That also has  NULL for StudyIDB.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data indicates that only `t2.studyida` can be `NULL` and all other columns should really be declared as `NOT NULL`.
If so, I suggest this simpler query:

```sql
SELECT studyida, b.studyidb, gender, age
     , CASE WHEN a.age IS NULL THEN 'b'
            WHEN b.age IS NULL THEN 'a'
                               ELSE 'a and b' END as source
FROM   t1 a
FULL   JOIN t2 b USING (studyida, gender, age)
ORDER  BY studyida, gender, age;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=547532c16967f6e9a411c533b0288f3d)*

The `USING` clause is convenient for identically named join columns. Only a single instance of the joining column is in the result set, effectively what `COALESCE(a.col, b.col)` gives you otherwise. (You might just use `SELECT *`.)
You can still reference source columns with table-qualification, like `a.age`.

I reduced to a single `age` column and added `source`. You may or may not want that.

Either way, "age" is subject to bitrot, almost always the wrong choice for a table column, and should typically be replaced by "birthday" or similar.

Comment: Hi Erwin. Can you spare some time, answer this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291056/plpgsql-one-input-get-all-the-related-feilds-columns-to-json-failed