# plpgsql one input get all the related fields/columns to json failed

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Try to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285556/how-to-query-3-tables-with-one-to-many-relationship-along-with-json-aggregation) question then found out, I cannot solve it.

Basic idea: propagate twice, from country_id propagate to state_id, state_id propagate to city_id twice.Then the country_id need be joined twice. when we do `array_agg` on state level, we need explicitly **join country_id**, during city level we also need using **join country_id**.

Reference link: https://github.com/hettie-d/NORM/tree/master/sql
Basic idea, input one country_id, all the relevant country, state, city level information will be transformed to json format.

---

Prepare. I use **country_id**, **state_id**, **city_id**, since they are more descriptive.

```
begin;
create table public.country(country_id bigint primary key , name text, leader text);
create table public.states(state_id bigint primary key, name text, population bigint,country_id bigint REFERENCES public.country (country_id));
create table public.cities(city_id bigint,name text,state_id bigint REFERENCES public.states (state_id));
insert into public.country values ( 1,    'India', 'Narendra Modi');
insert into public.country values ( 2 ,   'USA', 'Joe Biden');
insert into public.country values ( 3  ,  'Australia', 'Scott Morrison');
insert into public.states values( 1    ,'California'            , 39500000 , 2);
insert into public.states values(  2   , 'Washington'            , 7610000 ,2 );
insert into public.states values( 4   , 'Karnataka'            , 64100000,1);
insert into public.states values(  5   , 'Rajasthan'            , 68900000,1 );
insert into public.states values(  6   , 'Maharashtra'            , 125700000,1  );
insert into public.cities values(  1   , 'Mumbai'            , 6  );
insert into public.cities values(  2   , 'Pune'            , 6  );
insert into public.cities values(  3   , 'San Francisco'            , 1  );
commit;
```

--- create composite types.

```
begin;
create type city_record as(city_name text);
create type state_record as (state_name text, population bigint,cities city_record[]);
create type country_record as (country_name text, leader text, states state_record[]);
commit;
```

---

array transport

```
create or replace
function array_transport (all_items  anyarray) returns setof text
 returns null on null input
language plpgsql   as
$body$
declare
  item  record;
begin
foreach   item  in array all_items
loop
   return next(to_json(item)::text);
   end loop;
end;
$body$;
```

--the main function country_select_json

```
create or replace  function country_select_json (_country_id bigint)
    returns country_record[]
    as
$$
    declare
        _result text;

    begin
        select array_agg(single_item)
            from (select
                      array_agg(row(
                                        co.name,
                                        co.leader,
                                        (select array_agg(row
                                                        (s.name,
                                                        s.population,
                                                            (select array_agg
                                                                    (row
                                                                        (c.name)::city_record)
                                                                    from cities c
                                                                        join states s using (state_id)
                                                                    where s.country_id = co.country_id)
                                                        )::state_record) from states s where s.country_id = co.country_id
                                        )
                                    )::country_record)
        as single_item
        from country co
        where co.country_id = _country_id)y into _result;
--        raise info 'state_record test:  %', _result;
        return (_result);
    end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

run
`select * from array_transport(country_select_json(1));`

```
 {"country_name":"India","leader":"Narendra Modi","states":[{"state_name":"Karnataka","population":64100000,"cities":[{"city_name":"Mumbai"},{"city_name":"Pune"}]},{"state_name":"Rajasthan","population":68900000,"cities":[{"city_name":"Mumbai"},{"city_name":"Pune"}]},{"state_name":"Maharashtra","population":125700000,"cities":[{"city_name":"Mumbai"},{"city_name":"Pune"}]}]}
(1 row)
```

country level, state level ok, but the city level is wrong. How to solve this problem.
Expected Result:

```
 {"country_name":"India","leader":"Narendra Modi","states":[{"state_name":"Karnataka","population":64100000,"cities":[NULL]},{"state_name":"Rajasthan","population":68900000,"cities":[NULL]},{"state_name":"Maharashtra","population":125700000,"cities":[{"city_name":"Mumbai"},{"city_name":"Pune"}]}]}
```

---

**update 2022-03-04.**

```
(select array_agg
(c.name) as city_name
from cities c
join states s using (state_id)
where s.country_id = co.country_id)
```

Now  I know the problem: because the propagate is first from city, then to state then country. Once function input the `country_id` then all the country related city name will be pulled together.

Comment: So it is wrong. How is it wrong? What should be there instead?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I updated the expected result.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I found out the problem, It's just don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Does this query answer your needs ? ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tUsqgLzHVbD7siBEnLyi5R/1))

```
with ci as (select cities.state_id,jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('city_name',cities.name)) as cities from cities group by state_id)
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_build_object(
    'country_name',c.name,
    'leader',c.leader,
    'states', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
        'state_name',s.name,
        'population',s.population,
        'cities',ci.cities
    ))
))
from country c left join states s on s.country_id = c.country_id 
left join ci on ci.state_id = s.state_id
where c.country_id = 1
group by c.name,c.leader

// Result
{
"country_name": "India",
"leader": "Narendra Modi",
"states": [
    {
        "state_name": "Maharashtra",
        "population": 125700000,
        "cities": [
            {
                "city_name": "Mumbai"
            },
            {
                "city_name": "Pune"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "state_name": "Rajasthan",
        "population": 68900000,
        "cities": null
    },
    {
        "state_name": "Karnataka",
        "population": 64100000,
        "cities": null
    }
]
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But the idea is that no orm. which means one countryid pull all the info. I can figure it out use normal join. but the point  is:  https://github.com/hettie-d/NORM